# Load another page in PHP using a loader while using a simple HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, loader

I'm quite new to PHP. So I'm here to briefly explain my question.

Recently, I started building my site for an online tool, so it has an `input` box  like this. (I've not designed it fully yet.) (Page URL: `index.php`)

[image: Input Box]

I made it to fetch some datas from a social media site! As you can see, there is written "Enter Page URL". Users must have to put the URL of that page.

I should put the HTML content also! Here's it.

```
<form method="get" action="download.php">
<input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Enter Page URL" required />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download" />
</form>
```

The URL of the `action` page is `download.php`. Due to heavy PHP codes inside the `download.php`, the page responds very slow! Sometimes even it even takes upto 5 seconds to load. Only I know what is there, sharing everything isn't a good idea at all! Users might be thinking, it's their network issue or a site problem or something like that! Being irritated, they're leaving there.

Instead of loading the another page, I wanna put the `download.php` page inside the `index.php` page with a loader.

Content inside the `download.php` page looks almost like this.

[image: Download Page]

What if I put the `download` page in the `index` page with a loader like this? (Loader Image URL: http://webplayer.d8u.in/loading.gif)

[image: Example]

For example, if I return back from a playing video in YouTube mobile website, a loader appears & then suddenly we start seeing the video list! Including another pages in PHP can be done by `include` or `file_get_contents()`, but I dunno how to execute this with a loader (not by refreshing the current page). I guess there're so many answers of this in the internet, but I couldn't find any of them! Asking here was a better idea for me.

So, how can I do this using jQuery & PHP?

Comment: did you try sending by Ajax?

Comment: No, I didn't try it yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want change content of the page without refreshing page you have to use javascript exacly the `AJAX`. Read about https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 2):

This is not the exact code, but I think you will get the main idea on how to compete your code with ajax

```
function sendmyform(){
    var val = $('#myfield').val();
    $('#loadingbar').show();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "download.php",
        data: { name: val }
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        //msg here is the returned data from dowload.php
        $('#loadingbar').hide();
        $('#myfield').val('');
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<div id="loadingbar" style="display:none">Loading...</div>
<input id="myfield" type="text" name="url" placeholder="Enter Page URL" required />
<input type="button" onclick="sendmyform()" value="Download" />
```

something like this :)
more documentation here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/